# How to prove that $ab=a^2+4ab+4b^2$ is not true?

Tags: solution-verification

Basically the title, this problem is from statistics so $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers including 0.

Comment: Take $a=b=1$. $\quad $

Comment: More generally, if you want to show that some identity is false, then you need to come up with specific values that show that the identity does not hold.

Comment: 'Not true' means that it doesn't have solution or that it doesn't hold for every parameter?

Comment: it is true when $a=b=0$

Answer (score 6):

Hint

$$\implies a^2+3ab+4b^2=0$$

$$\iff0=4(a^2+3ab+4b^2)=(2a+3b)^2+7b^2$$

Comment: Okay, I might have asked a wrong question I actually wanted to prove it was unequal with an inequality sign, but did not know how to write it down so just put not true. Does it change the case if it is has to be proven unequal?

Comment: It does. His solution will still give you a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the claim is that "$ab=a^2+4ab+4b^2$ for all natural numbers $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$." As pointed out in the comments, it suffices to provide a single pair of natural numbers for which this fails to show the statement does not hold. If $a=b=1$, then the claim states:
$$ 1=1+4+4=9$$
which is a false statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof by counterexample**. To help find values to select for this, rearrange the equation so that all variables are on one side: $$ ab=a^2+4ab+4b^2 $$ $$ 0=a^2+3ab+4b^2 $$ So, if $ a $ and $ b $ are both positive numbers, then $ a^2+3ab+4b^2 $ will be a positive number and successfully disprove the equation. For simplicity, let's choose $ a = 1 $ and $ b = 1 $ and substitute in these values into the original equation: $$ 1 \times 1=1^2+4\times 1 \times 1+4\times 1^2 $$
$$ 1 =1+4+4 $$
$$ 1 =9 $$
Since $ 1 \neq 9$, then $ a = 1 $ and $ b = 1 $ provide a sufficient counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the degree of every term is 2. Let $a=xb$ to replace a variable. Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, note that $x$ must be rational.

$$xb^2=(x^2+4x+4)b^2$$

Either $b=0$, and hence $a=0$, or

$$x=x^2+4x+4$$

$$0=x^2+3x+4$$

which is now a quadratic in one equation. One can then easily verify that this quadratic has no rational solutions by the rational roots theorem. Furthermore, since the discriminant is negative, there aren't any real solutions.

So the only real solution is $a=b=0$.